# How to solve this initial value problem with $\tan(x)$ as coefficient?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x_1' = -(\tan t)x_1 + 3\cos^2t$$ 
$$x_2' = x_1 + (\tan t)x_2 + 2\sin t$$

$$x_1(0) = 4$$ $$x_2(0) = 0$$

I have tried to write them in the form:

$$ (D + \tan t)x_1 = 3\cos^2t$$  and
$$(D-\tan t) x_2 - x_1 - 2\sin t = 0$$

I then multiplied the second equation by $(D+\tan t)$ and substitute the first equation into the second but that just seems to complicate the problem more.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, far as I can see, the following makes sense only in $t\in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$. This is fine because $\tan t$ anyway blows up at $\pm \pi/2$, and the equations themselves are tenuous at the point and hence beyond.

---

Multiply the first equation with $\cos t$ and rearrange to get:

$$ \frac{\dot{x_1}\cos t + x_1 \sin t}{\cos^2 t} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left(\frac{x_1}{\cos t} \right) = 3 \\ \implies \frac{x_1(t)}{\cos t} - 4 = 3t \implies x_1(t) = (4+3t)\cos t$$

Feeding this into the second equation,

$$\dot{x_2} - x_2 \tan t = (4 + 3t)\cos t + \sin t$$

Multiply the above by $\cos t$ to get

$$\dot{x_2} \cos t - x_2 \sin t = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} (x_2 \cos t) = (4+3t)\cos^2 t+ \sin t \cos t$$

I'll leave it to you to integrate the above.